# LOB Segment is listed in DBA_SEGMENTS, but has not corresponding row in DBA_LOBS

Tags: oracle

I am trying to find the column (or table) that belongs to a rather big LOB segment:

```
select segment_name, segment_type, bytes 
from dba_segments 
where segment_name = 'SYS_LOB0000103936C00014$$';
```

returns:

```
SEGMENT_NAME              | SEGMENT_TYPE | BYTES
--------------------------+--------------+-------------
SYS_LOB0000103936C00014$$ | LOBSEGMENT   | 422877069312
```

However when I try to find the corresponding table:

```
select table_name, column_name, segment_name, tablespace_name, index_name 
from dba_lobs 
where segment_name = 'SYS_LOB0000103936C00014$$';
```

No rows are returned.

Is there any other place where the information about that LOB segment is stored?

This is an Oracle 11.2.0.4 (RAC) running RHEL 6.8

Comment: Check if it's in recycle bin, e.g. `select * from user_recyclebin where object_name like 'SYS_LOB%'`  (or  in `dba_recyclebin` )

Comment: @a1ex07: thanks for the suggestion, but the recyclebin is disabled on that system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible reason is setting a LOB column unusable:

```
SQL> create table t1 (c1 number, c2 clob);

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1 values (1, 'A');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select segment_name from dba_lobs where table_name = 'T1' and column_name = 'C2';

SEGMENT_NAME
------------------------------
SYS_LOB0000015673C00002$$

SQL> select segment_name from dba_segments where segment_name = 'SYS_LOB0000015673C00002$$';

SEGMENT_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SYS_LOB0000015673C00002$$

SQL> alter table t1 set unused column c2;

Table altered.

SQL> select  table_name, column_name from dba_lobs where segment_name = 'SYS_LOB0000015673C00002$$';

no rows selected

SQL> select segment_name from dba_segments where segment_name = 'SYS_LOB0000015673C00002$$';

SEGMENT_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SYS_LOB0000015673C00002$$
```

To find the table the orphaned LOB column belongs to:

```
select u.name, o.name TABLENAME, decode(bitand(c.property, 1), 1, ac.name, c.name) as column_name
from sys.obj$ o, sys.col$ c, sys.attrcol$ ac,sys.lob$ l,sys.obj$ lo,sys.obj$ io,
sys.user$ u,sys.ts$ ts
where o.owner# = u.user#
and o.obj# = c.obj#
and c.obj# = l.obj# and c.intcol# = l.intcol#
and l.lobj# = lo.obj# and l.ind# = io.obj# and l.ts# = ts.ts# and c.obj# =
ac.obj#(+)
and c.intcol# = ac.intcol#(+) and lo.name ='SYS_LOB0000015673C00002$$';

NAME                           TABLENAME                      COLUMN_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------ --------------------------------
BP                             T1                             SYS_C00002_16120712:10:58$
```

To remove the column and LOB segment:

```
SQL> alter table t1 drop unused columns;

Table altered.

SQL> select segment_name from dba_segments where segment_name = 'SYS_LOB0000015673C00002$$';

no rows selected
```

Based on: [Orphaned Lobs after marking LOB column unused (Doc ID 461651.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=461651.1)

Comment: That looks promising. Unfortunately I don't have access to the `SYS.xx` views in your query. But I can find a CLOB column that is hidden using `DBA_TAB_COLS`. Is there a way I can verify that that column is the one that belongs to the "orphaned" LOB segment using "normal" DBA_XXX views?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't think so. I couldn't find any dictionary view for this. Even `DBA_` views are filtered, sometimes you need to query the dictionary directly. For example, an unused column is not listed in `DBA_LOBS`, because of this (from the view definition): `and bitand(property,32768) != 32768 ;          /* not unused column */`

Comment: Another reason for this appears to be lobs in the recyclebin, where they still appear in DBA_OBJECTS but not DBA_LOBS